# How can I recover a filesystem in VMWare?

Tags: data-recovery, vmware, vmware-workstation

This question is hard to ask clearly: I am having filesystem issues on my Ubuntu VMWare virtual machine which runs in VMWare WorkStation 15 Pro. I don't believe the problems are VMWare itself, but something that occurred within the virtual machine in Ubuntu. The specific issue is that the filesystem is locked into read-only mode no matter what, even after fscks.

If I were running this Ubuntu instance on my bare-metal machine, in this type of situation, I would insert a Linux LiveCD into my disk drive or USB drive, and I would configure BIOS or UEFI to boot to the USB drive. I would then access the filesystem that exists on the hard disk to try and recover my files. Note that the files are not yet corrupted and the OS is bootable, but I can't really do anything once it boots because absolutely no writes can occur to the filesystem, which means I can't even mount a USB drive, can't use web browsers, and so on...

I don't know how to do the above in VMWare Workstation. I don't want to boot up a new VM with a LiveeCD, but instead, I want to boot a LiveCD on top of the VM I am trying to troubleshoot in such a way that the LiveCD will be able to "see" the underlying VM's drives and filesystem.

Note that I tried mapping the disk to my host filesystem (using DiskMount) in VMWare's VM -> Settings -> Hard Disk but the host machine is Windows and doesn't recognize the filesystem, it says the drive must be formatted, which of course is a horrible idea.

Comment: Have you tried VMWare DiskMount?

Comment: (1) Your first thought seems pretty good.  You should be able to boot your VM from a Live CD — or from an image of such a CD in a file on your Windows disk.  Check VMware documentation. (2) I would expect that you can mount new filesystems even if your root is mounted read-only.  What happened when you tried?  Try using the `-n` (``--no-mtab``) option.

Comment: You can mount a USB bootable disk and boot to that.  If I recall from my experiments you have to basically mount the disk in a raw format, you can't attach the device, as a literal USB drive though.

Comment: "but I can't really do anything once it boots because absolutely no writes can occur to the filesystem..." Make sure you take a snapshot of your VM first so that if you *do* perform any accidental writes, you can easily undo them.